# Two table views in one view controller swift with didSelectRowAtIndexPath in swift2.0

Tags: swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have two table views in one view controller. Let's assume the tables as table1 and table2. When I'm selecting a row in table1 I want to change the data in table2. How do I do that? (I cannot use segue identifiers because these tables are in one window)

My Code is as follows.And In my table1 i have lessons1 array.In table2 i have Lessons2 array. So Now i want to click on the second row of table1 and display the data in resources array in table2.likewise. Can u please help me with the code.I tried as follows.But I know it's totally wrong

```
 let Resources = ["Word Doc on Probability", "Extra Sums", "Homework","",""]

 let lessons1 = ["Term1", "Term2"," Term3"]

 let Lessons2 = ["Create a set theory", "Draw Ven Diagrams", "iOS Developer Tips"]

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
// Return the number of items in the sample data structure.

var count:Int?

if tableView.tag == 3 {
    count = lessons1.count
}
 else if tableView.tag == 4 {
    count = Lessons2.count
} return count!


}
       func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell:UITableViewCell?

if tableView.tag == 3 {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextCell3", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell!.textLabel!.text = lessons1[row]

}

 else if tableView.tag == 4 {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextCell4", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell!.textLabel!.text = Lessons2[row]

}

return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
  ////this code is wrong/////
let row = indexPath.row
if tableView.tag == 3 {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextCell4", forIndexPath: indexPath)


        cell.textLabel!.text = Objectives[row]
        lessons.reloadData()

    }

}
```

Comment: have you set tag in    **super.viewDidLoad()** ?

Comment: **table1.tag = 1** And **table2.tag = 2**

Comment: yes in the storyboard i set that

Answer (score 0):

A tableView reflects the data that is stored in your model.  When a row is selected in `table1`, update the data in the model for `table2` and then call `table2.reloadData()`.

```
@IBOutlet tableView1: UITableView!
@IBOutlet tableView2: UITableView!

let Resources = ["Word Doc on Probability", "Extra Sums", "Homework","",""]

let lessons1 = ["Term1", "Term2"," Term3"]

let Lessons2 = ["Create a set theory", "Draw Ven Diagrams", "iOS Developer Tips"]

var dataForTable1 = [String]()
var dataForTable2 = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dataForTable1 = lessons1
    dataForTable2 = Lessons2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of items in the sample data structure.

    var count = 0

    if tableView.tag == 3 {
        count = dataForTable1.count
    }
    else if tableView.tag == 4 {
        count = dataForTable2.count
    }

    return count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell?

    if tableView.tag == 3 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextCell3", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let row = indexPath.row
        cell!.textLabel!.text = dataForTable1[row]

    }

    else if tableView.tag == 4 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextCell4", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let row = indexPath.row
        cell!.textLabel!.text = dataForTable2[row]

    }

    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let row = indexPath.row
    if tableView.tag == 3 {
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            dataForTable2 = Resources
            tableView2.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You need to give a better example of what your two tables are showing.  For instance, if you have a list of words, your first table might be the letters of the alphabet, and the second table might be all of the words that start with that letter.  In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you would get the letter corresponding to the row of table one, and then filter the array of words to create the array that will be displayed in table 2.  Then you'd call `table2.reloadData()` and it would use that array to display the words.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    if tableView.tag == 3 
    {
        if indexPath.row == 1 
        {
            Lessons2 = Resources
            lessons.reloadData() //table2 is data reload
        }
    }
}
```